# No space left on root - almost immediately after re-install

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, root, disk, disk-usage

Yesterday I re-installed Ubuntu on my laptop. Today, whilst running `npm i` for a cloned repo, I got a no space error. [Error displayed in terminal window following npm i](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKLXo.png)

It said that there was no space in root. I have dual boot Windows and Ubuntu on a 1TB system. Ubuntu should be allocated about 60GB.

[disk allocation of memory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0fgD.png)

I tried to find a way to remove items from root, but there are two issues here, it's a temporary fix, and I don't want to delete files which I don't know what they do. `df -h` gives the following:

[teminal window of df -h](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lMl4.png)

I am a noob at partitioning hard-drives and data storage. I will be cloning repos and running `npm i` on the daily. Please help me find a way to set up my system so I don't have issues with storage.

Additional Info: On initial installation of Ubuntu, I created a partition from witin windows and then installed Ubuntu with some custom settings, (*I followed a guide*). This guide allocated a swap (no idea what it does). In the disk image above file partition 9 i s not mounted, but  partition 8 is mounted at root. I dont know what this means, but maybe it helps with diagnosis!

Thank you for reading, I hope you can help :)

peace x

Edit: after further investigation, I can see all of the files present before the re-install are still there on the un-mounted partition. See: [Devices & Location shows old files still exist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhkIu.png)
This is NOT what I thought happened when I clicked "Re-install ubuntu". I thought It would wipe the partition and start fresh...

**Solved** **Solved** **Solved**

After a long time of reading other posts I finally saw the light!

Re-installing Ubuntu only used one partition of my hard drive. It left the old files intact. I had to delete the old partition, wiping the old data, then expand the new ubuntu partition to the right, now there is enough space and you can see from `df -h` that the allocated space for the root is now much larger! :)[Increased size from 15GB to 46GB (33%)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2Czd.png)

Comment: Partition 7, 8 & 9 are there for ubuntu

Comment: I think the following needs to be done: clean up partitions and allocate more memory to the existing partition being used for ubuntu. I am not sure if this is correct and I wouldn't know how to do this... So maybe a complete factory reset of my entire computer is in order... That I can manage, but I wouldn't learn how to fix this and I have no way to back eveything up where I am right now :P Yay, computing :)

Comment: You've not provided any Ubuntu product details (what system, Server? Desktop? Core?) as the minimum disk requirements differ for each, Ubuntu Desktop recommends 25GB for example, but you appear to have allocated only 15GB where 25GB (assuming desktop) is the minimum for all releases from Ubuntu Desktop 17.10 and later.

Answer (score 0):

Re-installing Ubuntu only used one partition of my hard drive. It left the old files intact. I had to delete the old partition (this wiped the old data), then expand the new ubuntu partition to the right, now there is enough space and you can see from df -h that the allocated space for the root is now much larger!

[33% is now used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ut3oI.png)